# Store object for each user

Tags: php, server, client-server, session-state

I have an object which is holding the state for specific user... I need this object to be aviable while the user in on one of the pages in my site.

**My question is, where to save this object?**

Database? => to many queries... To build the state object many queries needs to be performed... and the object must be rebuilt for each page...

SESSION? =>  read the object from the database and store it in  $_SESSION. But each time the user swich page the object is serialized and deserialized... this affects the page loading time because the object serialization is heavy function....

COOKIE? => I need to access the state object from the server...

Is there any other option?

What is the common approach in this case?

Comment: What's your problem with SESSION?

Comment: i have a large object... and session save only text....

Comment: cant serialize it fast enough

Comment: You can save an object/array in session then access it as if it was a regular variable.
if you do `$_SESSION['user'] = $user_object`, you'll be able to access data like `$_SESSION['user']->name`. Of course, name can be any attribute you're trying to access.

Comment: Have you benchmarked serializing it? I find it hard to imagine that serializing / deserializing an object would take any significant time compared to all the other things involved in an http request...